# PHP how do I set the date to one week in advance?

Tags: php

I have the day and the month from the database, stored in seperate variables. But if today is the 7th and I minus one week, it would be 0 same case for the month. And I want to add the `lo_date` to `lockin_period_date` and minus 3 months, as I want it to send an email to me 3 months in advance. How do I set the values I have from the database to the date I want? Please help.

```
<?php
include"connect_mysql.php";
$reminder_dates = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM registration_form");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($reminder_dates)){
$main_dob_day = $row['main_dob_day'];
$main_dob_month = $row['main_dob_month'];   
$main_dob_year = $row['main_dob_year'];

$joint_dob_day = $row['joint_dob_day'];
$joint_dob_month = $row['joint_dob_month'];
$joint_dob_year = $row['joint_dob_year'];

$loan_lo_day = $row['loan_lo_day'];
$loan_lo_month = $row['loan_lo_month'];
$loan_lo_year = $row['loan_lo_year'];

$lockin_period_day = $row['lockin_period_day'];
$lockin_period_month = $row['lockin_period_month'];
$lockin_period_year = $row['lockin_period_year'];

$legal_fee_clawback_day = $row['legal_fee_clawback_day'];
$legal_fee_clawback_month = $row['legal_fee_clawback_month'];
$legal_fee_clawback_year = $row['legal_fee_clawback_year'];     

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');   

$m = date("n"); 
$d = date("j"); 
$y = date("Y");
$time = time();
$today = date('n-j-Y', $time);


//main applicant birthday - reminder 7days in advance
$main_day = $main_dob_day-7;
if($main_day == $d && $main_dob_month == $m){
echo "Mail Sent!";  
}
//

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$oneWeekAdv=$main_dob_year.'-'.$main_dob_month.'-'.$main_dob_day;
$oneWeekAdv=strtotime(date("y-m-d", strtotime($oneWeekAdv)) . " -1 week");
$oneWeekAdv=date('m-d', $oneWeekAdv);
```

Comment: This won't work - The second parameter to `date()` is a timestamp.

Comment: @navnav How do I change the date $main_dob_day - $main_dob_month to 1 week before?

Comment: @navnav How do I remove the year? Cause I want it to remind me every year on the same date.

Comment: @navnav now is 12-25. It should be 7-10? since I set it to 7-17

Comment: okay, **now** it should work...It's 4 o'clock in the morning (so it's not my fault xD)

Answer (score 2):

A [working solution](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0jbvUH) would be:

```
$main_day = date( 'n-j-Y', strtotime( "today -1 week"));
```

To apply it to your use-case:

```
$time = mktime( 0, 0, 0,  $main_dob_month, $main_dob_day, $main_dob_year);
$main_day = date( 'n-j-Y', strtotime( "-1 week", $time)); echo $main_day;
```

Comment: @navnav - Correct, the sample code does this and I was confused. After rereading the OP, it should be into the future. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong. The OP asks to 'minus 1 week'. Sorry.